# How to increase div size based on another div's position - vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, css, width

I'm working on a click and slide out panel feature of a new dashboard.

Goal is to accomplish this without the use of jQuery-UI or jQuery, pure Javascript or in an Angular.

[image]

**Codepen:**
http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/gbVpry

Clicking and dragging the red div, I'm able to get a new x position, I've tried adding that value to the width of the `drag-container` (the orange div) that is the div that's suppose to stretch out.

So far all the techniques I've tried haven't worked.

Do you see what I'm doing wrong here?

```
window.onload = addListeners();

var xPosition = 0;

var wW = window.innerWidth;
console.log(wW);

function addListeners() {
    document.getElementById('drag-container').addEventListener("click", getClickPosition, false);

    document.getElementById('dragger').addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
}

function getClickPosition(e) {
    xPosition = e.clientX;
    console.log(xPosition);
}

function mouseUp() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
}

function mouseDown(e) {
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
}

function divMove(e) {

    var max = (window.innerWidth - 50);
    var x = event.clientX;
    var div = document.getElementById('dragger');
    var offset = div.offsetWidth/2;
    var orangeDiv = document.getElementById('drag-container');

    //console.log(max);

    if (x > (100 + offset) && x < (max+offset)) {

        div.style.position = 'absolute';

        div.x = xPosition;

        div.style.left = (e.clientX - offset) + 'px';

          //orangeDiv.offsetWidth = (orangeDiv.offsetWidth + x);
        orangeDiv.style.width = (orangeDiv.style.width + x);

          console.log(orangeDiv.style.width);
        //console.log(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may have been a little overcomplicated, but there were a couple things I found. The fix below works for me, if that's the effect you're going for.

```
orangeDiv.style.width = (x - 40 + 'px');
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwejWg